# What integrated blog comments/forums solutions exist beyond Vanilla Forums?

Tags: forum, comments, recommendations

For the past year and a half, I've been running Vanilla Forums on my WordPress-based site

My favourite feature of Vanilla is that it integrates comments from the blog's front page into the forums, giving users the continuity of a single sign-on.

The downsides are that Vanilla loads slowly, performs rather poorly on iPads (a source of irony given my site's subject matter), randomly logs users out with some frequency, and generally annoys the forum regulars.

I would like to replace Vanilla with different forums software. Ideally, this new solution would:

- Integrate with blog comments and
- Import our 1.5 years' worth of data from Vanilla.

Is there anything out there that would fit my needs?

Comment: The post that my question has been redirected to doesn't actually answer my question. This isn't the first time I've gotten an impersonal smack down in response to a genuine question on Stack Exchange. This is a very newbie unfriendly place.

Comment: The linked question is a community wiki meant to reduce requests for recommendations, which is currently [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site - otherwise, it could become a beacon for advertising and self-promotion. You can always use the Chat room to ask if a question is a good fit here or not.

Comment: I've got a really specific question here, answers to which would have provided useful information to more people than just myself, I think. If that's not in keeping with the mission of Stack Exchange, then I can't imagine what Stack Exchange's mission is. I'll go ask my question somewhere else.